# Using services in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to set up my Angular 2 app such that my main **app.component** checks whether I'm logged in and passes relevant data to a service, which is then passed onto my other components (**home.component**, etc).

Where I'm currently stuck is in trying to understand how to pass to and from a service variable. So I have an **app.service** like this:

```
@Injectable(){
    export class AppService {
      public logged: boolean;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I have an **app.component** like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private appService: AppService){
  var self = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if (user){ self.appService.logged = true; alert("True"); }
    }); 
  }
}
```

By running the alert I am able to confirm that I am indeed logged in. However, I am unable to retrieve the `self.appService.logged` state which I have set here.

This code, for instance, does nothing.

```
ngOnInit(){
if (this.appService.logged){ alert("Correct"); }
}
```

Comment: I have it hooked up to my **app.component**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `self`. If you use arrow functions `this.` keeps pointing to the current class.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private appService: AppService){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user){ this.appService.logged = true; alert("True"); }
    }); 
  }
}
```

The problem in your code is, that `this.appService.logged = true;` is in an async callback and very probably executed after the `ngOnInit()` is called.

I'd suggest you make your service variable a `BehaviorSubject` and subscribe to that to get notfied on value changes.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html contains some examples.